# Как блокируют доступ к сайтам? telnet vs. браузер

Tags: http, dns, маршрутизация

При попытке открыть Кинозал.тв в любом браузере перебрасывает на заглушку РосКомНадзора.

Москва, провайдер ОнЛайм, OS X 10.11.2 El Capitan. DNS у меня стоят гугловские. Запрос браузера идёт по правильному адресу, к CloudFlare – на этот же ip ресолвится имя сайта и с зарубежных vps'ов. В ответ в браузеры приходит просто редирект на заглушку:

[image: скриншот FireBug / Network панель]

Если же проделать соединение не браузером, а `telnet` на порт 80, то всё работает как положено – возвращается html страницы:

[image: скриншот telnet]

Это так же работает, если в telnet отправить все те же HTTP заголовки, что и шлёт браузер:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: kinozal.tv
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: uid=1234567; pass=XXXXXXXX; __cfduid=abcdefe0171f2defb37070b1428009916; stylet=0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Хотя заголовок про `gzip` лучше убрать, а то в терминал валится нечитаемый бинарный мусор компрессированного контента.

Пока единственная разница, которую нашёл – во времени: в telnet от момента соединения до отправки заголовков проходит пара секунд, пока я вручную сделаю paste. В браузере это происходит за миллисекунды. Надо попробовать с `curl`..

**Вопросы:** как и где происходит подмена ответа заблокированных серверов; Почему запросы из telnet обходят этот механизм?

**Нашёлся ответ** [habrahabr.ru/post/249433](https://habrahabr.ru/post/249433/) в конце ответа после **UPD**. Вкратце:

> Стоило вам присмотреться к трафику, который приходит на интерфейс от Ростелекома. Вероятно, DPI подключен параллельно, а не последовательно, и туда приходит только клиентский трафик. Т.к. DPI стоит явно ближе, чем вебсайт, пакет с Location от DPI приходит быстрее, чем реальный первый пакет от сайта, а пакет от сайта уже отбрасывается ядром ОС как ретрансмиссия, поэтому, если вы используете Linux, достаточно одной строки в iptables, чтобы обойти блокировку:
>
> ```
> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -m string --algo bm --string "http://95.167.13.50/?st" -j DROP
> ```

Comment: Все зависит от того как точно задан блокирующий фильтр. Попробуйте для начала установить [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) и использовать чтобы паслать запрос типа `GET http://kinozal.tv/ HTTP/1.1` и в заголовках задать только `Accept: text/html` или `User-Agent: Fiddler` и `Accept: text/html`. Нужно нащупать, что используется в блокирующем фильтре.

Comment: Важно понять, чтот Fiddler работает как прокси и в нем можно задать правила, чтобы он корректировал любой запрос автоматически. Так что если понять, что изменять, то с правильным фильтром можно будет работать в веб браузере а Fiddler мог бы делать необходимые корректировки запросов, чтобы обойти 
блокирующий фильтр. Но прежде всего нужно нащупать, что является критерием блокировки.

Comment: @Oleg я по обратному пути пошёл: хочу, чтобы telnet поймал редирект на заглушку. Ведь он отправляет точно те же данные, с того же ip и на тот же ip, что и браузер! И зачем мне fiddler, если и в телнете могу напечатать любые заголовки.

Comment: тогда в телнете надо точно повторить все HTTP заголовки запроса веб браузера для начала

Comment: @Oleg именно это и было проделано, я же обновил вопрос. С идентичными заголовками браузер: fail, telnet: success.

Comment: fiddler необходим для конечного решения, которое я описал выше. Да и ваботать с ним очень удобно потому, что он рассчинан на все, что может понадобиться в коммуникации через HTTP. Например, gzip ответы - не проблема. Click, и видешь декодированный ответ.

Comment: Может блокировка идет на уровне прокси? В конфигурации веб браузара точно нет прокси? Телнет ивязывается напрямую. В любом случае если: браузер: fail, telnet: success, то нужен третий эксперемент, чтобы нащупать разницу. Или же использовать sniffer и сравнивать запросы более детально.

Comment: отправлять запрос лучше не telnet-ом, а netcat-ом: `$ echo -ne 'GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ya.ru\r\n\r\n' | nc ya.ru 80`

Answer (score 5):

запустил такую команду на двух компьютерах, один из которых находится в рф (провайдер highlink), другой — в фрг:

```
$ echo -ne 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: kinozal.tv\r\n\r\n' | nc -i 1 kinozal.tv 80
```

сравнение вывода этих команд (оставлены лишь существенные фрагменты):

```
$ diff -ruaN kinozal.frg kinozal.rf
--- kinozal.frg 2016-01-22 11:51:53.000000000 +0000
+++ kinozal.rf  2016-01-22 11:51:01.000000000 +0000
@@ -1,13 +1,21 @@
-HTTP/1.1 200 OK
-Date: Fri, 22 Jan 2016 11:51:18 GMT
-Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
-Transfer-Encoding: chunked
-Connection: keep-alive
-Set-Cookie: __cfduid=df6ffc8c31e9a6f6f2e233c7f44bf81761453463478; expires=Sat, 21-Jan-17 11:51:18 GMT; pa
th=/; domain=.kinozal.tv; HttpOnly
-Server: cloudflare-nginx
-CF-RAY: 268b0bd3e28e2690-FRA
+HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
+Server: nginx/1.0.15
+Content-Type: text/html
+Content-Length: 173
+Connection: close
+Location: http://blocking.hl.ru:88

-505
+<html>
+<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
+<body bgcolor="white">
+<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
+<hr><center>nginx/1.0.15</center>
+</body>
+</html>
+
+------------0b0ac4bb16a6-ARN
+
+f77
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html><head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

дальше в обоих файлах идёт содержимое страницы, отдаваемой сайтом `kinozal.tv`.

---

как видно из вывода программы `diff`:

- изменены заголовки ответа сервера, благодаря чему браузер должен повторить запрос, но уже по адресу `http://blocking.hl.ru:88` (доменное имя *hl.ru* принадлежит тому самому провайдеру highlink);
- после заголовка вставлен ещё один блок *html* с текстом-заглушкой.

---

ваш провайдер, вероятно, использует что-то иное. может быть добавляется заголовок с перенаправлением, может быть добавляется блок с *javascript-ом*, выполняющим переход.

Comment: Я наблюдаю примерно то же, как и описал в вопросе. Только у вас diff рф / фрг, а у меня любой браузер / telnet,nc. И всё происходит на одном и том же компьютере в РФ, без прокси. Этот момент мне и не понятен: как фильтры отличают запрос браузера от сессии nc или telnet.

Comment: Вот, что интересно: ваша команда, с односекундной задержкой между отправкой строк, и у меня получает в ответ дописанный хедер редиректа на заглушку: [скриншот](http://imgur.com/yMo5Avd)

Comment: И в то же время, тот же nc без задержек, с вручную вставленным запросом и нажатым Enter отдаёт **чистый ответ**, без редиректа: [скриншот](http://imgur.com/kg0bgkT)